# Capture requesting url in node.js

Tags: node.js, url, express, request

I'm unsure of how to word this, sorry if its not straight forward.

When a user enter www.example.com in the browser address bar or an ip of my server running node.js I would like to get the incoming request and decide what to do from there:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
var target=app.get('host');
  console.log(target);
});

app.listen(8088,"0.0.0.0");
```

As a result I'm seeing 'undefined' printed on the console, rather than what was entered in the browser as I expected. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   // print host
   console.log(req.headers.host);

   // print path and request parameters
   console.log(req.url);
   res.end();
});
```